# Выдается ошибка при вызове функции front() в шаблоне очереди с++

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов, очередь, c++17

Я делаю очередь с помощью шаблона . Добавляю туда элементы в виде структур, однако при вызове функции front() (которая должна выводить первую добавленную структуру) выводит ошибку:

> error: cannot bind'std::basic_ostream' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream&&'

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>   // подключаем заголовочный файл очереди
#include <string>  // заголовочный файл для работы
                   // со строками типа string using namespace std;
struct Deb {
    int age;
    char FIO[20];
    char group[20];
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    Deb rer;
    queue<Deb> chek;
    int a;
    cout << "Введите количество елементво в очереди - ";
    cin >> a;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        cout << "Введитое возраст:  " << endl;
    t:
        cin >> rer.age;
        if (rer.age >= 80 || rer.age <= 16) {
            cout << "Некоректно введенный возраст. Введите еще 
                раз : " << endl;
                      goto t;
        }
        cout << "Введитое вашу фамилию:  " << endl;
        cin >> rer.FIO;
        cout << "Введитое вашу группу:  " << endl;
        cin >> rer.group;
        chek.push(rer);
    }
    cout << "    " << chek.size() << endl;
    cout << "     " << chek.front() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Имя, сестга, имя!" Код где?

Comment: Код добавил только что

Comment: Функция `front()` не может ничего выводить. Выводить должен оператор `<<`. Почему вы ожидаете, что это будет работать? Откуда оператор `<<` может знать, как выводить вашу структуру?

Comment: Функция front() должна выводить первый добавленный елемент в очереди, но я не знаю, как передать все поля структуры для функции front ()

Answer (score 5):

Метод [front](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/front) возвращает ссылку на первый элемент в очереди. В Вашем случае это будет ссылка на объект класса `Deb`:

```
auto& first = check.front(); // first имеет тип Deb&
```

Далее, Вам необходимо перегрузить оператор `<<` для типа `Deb`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Deb& d) { 
    return stream << d.age << " " 
                  << d.FIO << " " 
                  << d.group; 
}
```

Как справедливо заметил @AnT - `Deb` - пользовательский тип, в стандартной библиотеке для него нет перегруженного оператора `<<`, а это значит, что Вы должны реализовать его *самостоятельно*.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключается в том, что функция-член класса `front` возвращает ссылку типа `Deb &` на элемент очереди, имеющий тип `std::queue<Deb>`. Однако оператор `operator <<` не определен для потока `std::ostream` и объекта структуры `Deb`. Поэтому компилятор не знает, что делать в этом случае, и выдает сообщение об ошибке.

Самый простой способ обойти проблему - это сначала создать объект на основе возвращаемой ссылки из функции-члена класса `front`, а затем вывести на консоль члены этого объекта, так как они объявлены управлением доступом public (по умолчанию для структур).

Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

struct Deb 
{
    int age;
    char FIO[20];
    char group[20];
};

int main()
{
    std::queue<Deb> chek;
    Deb deb1 = { 20, "Maks Boll", "C++" };

    chek.push( deb1 );

    Deb deb2 = chek.front();

    std::cout << "age: " << deb2.age << ", FIO: " << deb2.FIO << ", group: " << deb2.group << '\n';

}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
age: 20, FIO: Maks Boll, group: C++
```

Если вы используете компилятор, который поддерживает C++ 17, то вы можете использовать так называемое структурно связанное объявление (***structured binding declaration***).

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа, которая показывает, как можно использовать такое объявление для вывода элементов структуры на консоль.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

struct Deb 
{
    int age;
    char FIO[20];
    char group[20];
};

int main()
{
    std::queue<Deb> chek;
    Deb deb = { 20,"Maks Boll", "C++" };

    chek.push( deb );

    const auto [ age, FIO, group] = chek.front();

    std::cout << "age: " << age << ", FIO: " << FIO << ", group: " << group << '\n';
}
```

Вывод программы:

```
age: 20, FIO: Maks Boll, group: C++
```

Кстати сказать, в C++ 17 также определена обобщенная функция `std;:size`, которую можно использовать со стандартными контейнерами и массивами. Поэтому вы также можете написать

```
#include <utility>

// ...

std::cout << "    " << std::size( chek ) << '\n';
```

вместо

```
cout << "    " << chek.size() << endl;
```

что делает программы более гибкой и стойкой к изменениям.

В противном случае, если компилятор не поддерживает стандарт C++ 17, вам самостоятельно следует определить такой оператор. К примеру, он может выглядеть следующим образом

```
std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const Deb &deb )
{
    return os << "age: " << deb.age << ", FIO: " << deb.FIO << ", group: " << deb.group;
}
```

Ниже приведена соответствующая демонстрационная программа.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

struct Deb 
{
    int age;
    char FIO[20];
    char group[20];
};

std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const Deb &deb )
{
    return os << "age: " << deb.age << ", FIO: " << deb.FIO << ", group: " << deb.group;
}

int main()
{
    std::queue<Deb> chek;
    Deb deb = { 20,"Maks Boll", "C++" };

    chek.push( deb );

    std::cout << chek.front() << '\n';;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль идентичен выводу, показанному для предыдущей демонстрационной программы:

```
age: 20, FIO: Maks Boll, group: C++
```